# Dataframe filter rows based on comparison with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I want to filter the one dataframe based on dates which falls in between dates of another dataframe.

I've tried the following code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Start':['1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016'], 
                    'end':['1/12/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/12/2016'], 
                   'Qty':[1, 2, 3, 4, 2],
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Start':['1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016'], 
                    'end':['1/6/2016', '1/6/2016', '1/6/2016'], 
                    'Price':[11, 12, 31],
                   })

df2[(df2['Start']>=df1['Start']) & (df2['end']<=df1['end'])]
```

It should select all three rows of df2. But gives this error:

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

P.S. Number of rows can't be same in my case.

Comment: It should select all three rows of df2

Comment: If start and end date of df2 falls between same of df1 then it should select those rows. In this case, all three should come as output

Comment: I changed it to <= but still same error

Answer (score 0):

You should have equal number of rows in both data frames for comparison.Here You have 5 rows in `df1` and 3 rows in `df2`.

Comment: Number of rows can't be same in my case. Now how can I compare it?

Comment: One approach is ,you can split the data frame with higher number of rows into two with one part equal to the number of rows in another data frame and then do the comparison.Then append  the second part to the final result

Answer (score 0):

- [`pandas.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) - Convert argument to datetime.
- [`DataFrame.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, placing NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Start':['1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016'],
                    'end':['1/12/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/12/2016'],
                   'Qty':[1, 2, 3, 4, 2],
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Start':['1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/1/2016'],
                    'end':['1/6/2016', '1/6/2016', '1/6/2016'],
                    'Price':[11, 12, 31],
                   })

# resize df2 shape
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index)

# convert argument to datetime.
df1['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start'])
df1['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['end'])

df2['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start'])
df2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end'])

print(df2[(df2['Start'] >= df1['Start']) & (df2['end'] <= df1['end'])])

       Start        end  Price
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-06   11.0
1 2016-01-01 2016-01-06   12.0
2 2016-01-01 2016-01-06   31.0
```